# htaccess in subfolder cant rewrite to file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In the root directory there's an htaccess file that directs everything that lands on it to goto a diff domain

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/
```

http://www.domain.com/123 = http://www.domain.com/

I have a folder named 'admin' within the root dir with another htaccess document inside it, I want that htaccess doc to point the root of itself to 'admin.php'

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /admin.php
```

http://www.domain.com/admin/ = http://www.domain.com/admin/admin.php

But no matter how I do it, I either get 500 Error or the rewrite rule from the main root doc over-rides it.

Hope that makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this (there are several) is probably exclude the admin directory from the RewriteRule in the root using a condition like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^admin/.*
RewriteCond $1 !^admin\.php
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/
```

Comment: Hmm, half worked. the admin directory now loads. but I get a 403 error in the dir 'Directory index forbidden by Options directive:' and if any rewrite rules are set in the htaccess doc in the /admin/ dir then the it just redirects to domian.com

Comment: My bad, the RewriteCond should exclude anything below admin. I updated the answer accordingly (didn't test it, but it should work).

Comment: Yeah it works still, but only half of it. I have these write rules in the htaccess inside /admin/:

'DirectoryIndex admin.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^meow$ /admin.php?action=meow'

if I goto /admin/meow/ it redirects to domain.com.

Comment: Where is your admin.php located? I assumed it was in /admin/admin.php, however if it is in the root requests to /admin.php will be redirected by the rule in the root dir. You can prevent this with an additional condition like this: RewriteCond $1 !^admin\.php. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: It was in /admin/ but I've given up now. Thanks for your help all the same.